# html/css why does margin-top of a inner-div bleed ouside the outer-div?

Tags: html, css, margin

I have a simple piece of html code like this

```
<div class="outer-div">
    <div class="inner-div" style="margin:1em"></div>
</div>
```

why does margin-top of the inner-div bleed out and not push the it down?
If I add a padding top in the outer-div of only 1px, the bleeding stops.

thanks!

Comment: this is [margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing)